# How to display image field, text field, etc. when something loads ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs

So I have this code: https://pastebin.com/PzqWtc6A which right now allows users to load files from their computer to a draggable list using the the `input` and `handleClick` method.

[image]

What I want to do now is load an image field, text fields, etc, above the list when the list loads. It should look something like this:

[image]

My question is where or how should I load a component or etc in my code to display the image/text fields above my list when the list loads?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question. Can't you just add the necessary JSX to the existing JSX in your main class? In case you copy-pasted that code from somewhere without understanding how it or React works, what exactly do you expect us to do? Teach you basic React? In case that's not what happened, please elaborate on the exact issue you're having.

Comment: Please post the relevent code here on SO and create a [Minimal Reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: @ChrisG I want to load something like the second picture above my list when my list loads. So I guess I can add JSX to my code but how would I make sure it only renders when the list is loaded or right before the list is loaded?

Comment: Assuming that the list is part of your state and an empty array initially, you can use conditional rendering: `<div>{this.state.list.length > 0 && <div>playlist info</div>}</div>`

Comment: @ChrisG So this will load the list when the array is filled right?

Comment: Yes: https://reactjs.org/docs/conditional-rendering.html

Comment: @ChrisG do you think I should create the input fields/textfields etc in a separate component on another file so it doesn't get to large or you think it will be good?

Comment: It's definitely a good idea to use a separate Component, yes. You don't want to have dozens of lines of JSX in a single component.

Comment: How would I render the component after the &&?

Comment: Nvm I think I got it @ChrisG

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly you want to display a form after all the files selected by the user are loaded, You can achieve that by having a state that keeps track of whether the files are loading or if it is complete, and in the render method you can conditionally render the form that you want to display above the list.

so you would have something like this in your state

```
this.state = {
files:[],
isLoadingFiles:true, 
}
```

then you can do

```
  // Now handle the array of promises we just created
  Promise.all(allReaders)
    .then(fileList => {
      console.log(fileList)
      // set the state that we have all the files
      this.setState({ files: fileList,isLoadingFiles:false });
    })
    .catch(error => {
       console.error(error)
    });
```

and now in render method you can do

```
render() {
    const {isLoadingFiles,files} = this.state;
    return (
    <div>
       <div>
         {!isLoadingFiles&&<div>The form you want to display</div>}
       </div>
      <div className="downloadMusic">...</div>
    </div>
```